# Como uma tag em um elemento de uma table com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tabela simples:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

mark {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table width="300px" border="1px" bordercolor="#FF0000">
  <tbody id="qtdPrecos">
    <tr id="precos">
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 92.4</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 137.48</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 108.27</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 129.25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Como eu faço para inserir a tag `<mark></mark>` no `<td>` que tem o menor valor com jQuery?

Assim:

```
<td class="pointer fmp-td"><mark>R$ 92.4</mark></td>
```

Comment: Primeiro, identifique a célula com o menor valor. Já conseguiu isso? Se sim, poste o código. Se não, descreva como você acha que é feito.

Comment: Não consegui. Eu pensei em listar todos os `<td>` que estão dentro da `<tr>` com o id `#precos` utilizando o `$.each` do jQuery depois pegar a que tiver o menor valor utilizando o `Math.min.apply(Math, variavel)`. Depois adicionar a tag e substituir as `<td>`. Mas não consegui

Comment: A ideia parece correta. Tem como postar mesmo assim este código que tentou fazer? Ajudará a identificar exatamente qual foi seu erro.

Comment: So consegui achar o menor valor: https://jsfiddle.net/newtech/gr9xn8as/

Comment: Certo. Agora você percorre todos os elementos `td`, verifica qual possui o valor igual ao mínimo e adiciona a tag `mark`.

Comment: Pergunta: e se houverem dois preços iguais, ambos deverão ser marcados ou qual seria, então, o critério de seleção?

Comment: Nunca vai ter dois preços iguais.Eu agrupo os valores iguais antes de listar na tabela

Comment: Você poderia editar o título da pergunta @usuario, está confuso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A idéia aqui é:

- Usar recursos do ES6 como [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) e [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) para retornar um array
- Usar o [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para retornar somente o conteúdo dos `tds`
- Aplicar a expressão regular `/[0-9.]/g` para capturar somente o valor numérico
- Por fim encontrar o menor e usar o [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) do jQuery para criar a marcação

```js
const tds = [...document.getElementsByTagName('td')].map(item => Number(item.innerHTML.match(/[0-9.]/g).join('')));
const menor = Math.min.apply(Math, tds);

$('td').each(function() {
  if ($(this).html().indexOf(menor) > -1) {
    const aux = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('').wrapInner('<mark>' + aux + '</mark>');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

mark {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300px" border="1px" bordercolor="#FF0000">
  <tbody id="qtdPrecos">
    <tr id="precos">
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 92.4</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 137.48</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 108.27</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 129.25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Como posso saber quais `features` do ES6 já posso utilizar em produção?

Comment: Muitos dos recursos já são suportados pelos novos browsers sem precisar usar um transpiler @RafaelAcioly. Podemos olhar [aqui](http://caniuse.com/#search=es6)  e [aqui](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) para ver a compatibilidade.

Answer (score 2):

Segue abaixo código comentado com cada etapa para marcar o menor valor com o `mark`.

```js
$(function() {

  function markMinValue() {
    var pricesTd = $('td', 'table #qtdPrecos #precos'),
      pricesValue = [],
      minValue,
      indexMinValue;

    // Percorre as linhas da tabela com preços
    $.each(pricesTd, function(indice, element) {
      // Armazena o valor de cada uma em uma variável temporária
      var value = $(element).text().replace('R$ ', '') * 1;
      // Adiciona no array o valor
      pricesValue.push(value);
    });

    // Busca o menor valor
    minValue = Math.min.apply(null, pricesValue);

    // Encontra o indice do menor valor
    indexMinValue = pricesValue.indexOf(minValue);

    // Marca o item com menor valor pelo indice encontrado
    $(pricesTd[indexMinValue]).wrapInner('<mark></mark>');

  }

  // Executa a função para marcar o item de menor valor
  markMinValue();

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

mark {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="300px" border="1px" bordercolor="#FF0000">
  <tbody id="qtdPrecos">
    <tr id="precos">
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 92.4</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 137.48</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 108.27</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 129.25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Vi que já responderam a pergunta, mas estou contribuindo com mais uma solução do problema, minha resposta foi baseada em soluções encontradas aqui: [Find the smallest value of a table row using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470002/find-the-smallest-value-of-a-table-row-using-javascript)
.

```js
//Percorre as TDS da table e monta um ARRAY
var valoresNaTd = $('#qtdPrecos tr td').map(function() {
  var valor = $(this).text().substr(2);
  return valor;
}).get();

//Localiza o valor mínimo no array
var valorMinimo = Math.min.apply(Math, valoresNaTd);

//Coloca o mark na TD de menor valor
$('#qtdPrecos tr td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().substr(2) == valorMinimo;
}).wrapInner('<mark></mark>');
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

mark {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300px" border="1px" bordercolor="#FF0000">
  <tbody id="qtdPrecos">
    <tr id="precos">
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 92.4</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 137.48</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 108.27</td>
      <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 129.25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos separar por passos o que deve ser feito:

1. Pegar todos os valores dentro de cada `td`.
2. Coloca-los em ordem de menor para maior.
3. Pegar o element com menor valor e inserir a tag `<mark></mark>` nele.

Passo 1:

Pegando todos os elementos:

```
$('#precos td.pointer');
```

Passo 2:

Colocar os elementos em ordem de acordo com o valor dentro do `HTML`, para isso podemos utilizar a função `sort()` que realiza um loop pegando de 2 em 2 elementos e comparando entre eles:

```
var values = $('#precos td.pointer').sort(function(current, next) {
    // Substitui a string R$ por "vazio" e pega apenas os 
    // valore dentro do HTML e transforma em números.
    var one = parseFloat(current.innerHTML.replace('R$', ''));
    var two = parseFloat(next.innerHTML.replace('R$', ''));

    // Verifica se o valor atual é maior ou menor que o próximo
    if (one < two) return -1;
    return 1;
});
```

Agora a variável `values` possui todos os elementos em ordem decrescente (menor para o maior), e assim podemos simplesmente pegar o primeiro elemento de `values` que sempre sera o maior e alterar o `HTML`

```
$(values[0]).html('<mark>'+values[0].innerHTML+'</mark>');
```

**Veja abaixo o código funcionando:**

```js
var values = $('#precos td.pointer').sort(function(current, next) {
    // Pega apenas os valore dentro do HTML e transforma em números.
    var one = parseFloat(current.innerHTML.replace('R$', ''));
    var two = parseFloat(next.innerHTML.replace('R$', ''));

    // Verifica se o valor atual é maior ou menor que o próximo
    if (one < two) return -1;
    return 1;
});

$(values[0]).html('<mark>'+values[0].innerHTML+'</mark>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="300px" border="1px" bordercolor="#FF0000">
   <tbody id="qtdPrecos">
      <tr id="precos">
         <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 92.4</td>
         <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 137.48</td>
         <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 108.27</td>
         <td class="pointer fmp-td">R$ 129.25</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Faltou só editar a explicação ali _"ordem crescente (maior para o menor)"_, no caso o `values` ficou do menor para o maior agora.